# STL iterators std::distance() error

Tags: c++, vector, stl, iterator, distance

I'm having such two typedefs:

```
typedef std::vector<int> Container;
typedef std::vector<int>::const_iterator Iter;
```

In the problem that I consider, I perform some operations on `Container Input`, and after that I would like to compute `std::distance(Input.begin(),itTarget)`, where `itTarget` is of the `Iter` type. But I'm getting this compiler error that `no instance of function template "std::distance" matches the argument list`, and only after casting, i.e., `std::distance(static_cast<Iter>(Input.begin()),itTarget)` everything works fine.

I wonder why is that?

Comment: Is it because `begin()` is not returning a `const_iterator`?

Comment: But somehow it should be able? http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/begin/

Comment: That's the way `const` and non-`const` overloads work. Only if `Input` is `const`-qualified will the `const` overload be called. Also, rather than casting the iterator, you can call specify the template type: `std::distance<Iter>(Input.begin(),itTarget)`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[std::distance](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/distance) is a template function, it can't accept different parameters. 
You need to use:

```
std::distance(Input.cbegin(),itTarget);
                    ^^
```

see [std::vector::cbegin](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/begin) link

Comment: and cbegin() returns const iterator?

Comment: @SimonRighley Some C++98 alternatives: `std::distance(const_cast<const Container&>(Input).begin(),itTarget)` (or `std::distance(static_cast<const Container&>(Input).begin(),itTarget)` if seeing "const_cast" makes you scared), `std::distance<Iter>(Input.begin(),itTarget)`, and of course the one from the question.

Answer (score 5):

`Input.begin()` returns an `iterator` instead of a `const_iterator`, and your second argument is a `const_iterator`, so the two arguments are basically of a different type. You can use `cbegin()` if you have access to C++11 Features.

A second way of doing it:
Every iterator is convertible into a const_iterator by assignment

```
std::vector<int> myVector(100);
std::vector<int>::iterator it = myVector.begin();
std::vector<int>::const_iterator cit = it;
```

If you have to pack things into the function call you could use some cast magic:

```
std::distance( ((const Container*)&Input)->begin(), itTarget );
```

If Input is const, the compiler is forced to use the const-version of begin(), which returns a const_iterator.

Comment: A cast works with vector's iterators because they're usualy simply a typedef for `T*` and `const T*`. It might not work with iterators that are classes.

Comment: Scratch that, looks like `iterator` is always supposed to be convertible to `const_iterator`.

Comment: Convertible, yes. Castable? I wouldn't be that sure. Updated my answer.

Comment: +1 but I don't like your C-ish cast :) `template<typename T> const T& const_treatment(const T& obj) { return obj; }` and use it like `const_treatment(Input).begin();`

Comment: You could also create a reference to a const vector and use that instead.